# Where is the build and go button?(xcode 4.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am very new to the xcode.I just create a foundation tool app.But I just can't see the build and go button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is *no "Build & Go" button in Xcode 4.1*. But you can do exactly the same thing by :

- Selecting your desired configuration from the **Scheme dropdown** menu (next to the Run button)
- Clicking on the **Run** button (or hitting ***Cmd+R***)